# Routing parent component Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this path route

```
mydomain/app/form/hold
```

I need to create a route when i acces to

```
mydomain/app/form -> app/form/form.component
```

that redirect to

```
mydomain/app/dashboard -> app/dashboard/dashboard.component
```

this is mya form route

```
import { Dashboard } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', children: [
      { path: '',redirectTo: 'dashboard',  pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'hold',  loadChildren: () => System.import('./hold/hold.module')  },
      { path: 'dashboard', component:Dashboard}
    ]
  },
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  Dashboard
  ],


imports: [
    Select2Module,
    NKDatetimeModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  schemas:  [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export default class FormModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

My dashboard.module

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '', component: Dashboard, pathMatch: 'full' }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    WidgetModule,
    UtilsModule,
    RickshawChartModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    Dashboard,
    GeoLocationsWidget,
    BootstrapCalendar,
    MarketStatsWidget
  ]
})
export default class DashboardModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

the problem is when i add Dashboard in NgModule declarations i got error, when remove dashboard from declarations i got error too. I cant redirect to dashboard component

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Type Dashboard is part of the declarations of 2 modules: DashboardModule and FormModule! Please consider moving Dashboard to a higher module that imports DashboardModule and FormModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes Dashboard then import that NgModule in DashboardModule and FormModule.

Comment: Is FormModule also one of your modules?

Comment: yup my form route is inside of my FormModule

Comment: OK. Sounds like you've declared Dashboard in both modules as per the error message. Any one component can be declared in one and only one module.

Comment: nah, how can i redirect to dashbord if i cant declare dashboard component in formModule

Comment: Can you post the formsModule code as well?

Comment: I already edit my post Ty

Comment: i already add my dashboard module

Comment: Why does the dashboard module have the route if it is already defined in the FormModule?

Comment: dashboard has own path like mydomain/app/dashboard but i wanna make if someone goin to mydomain/app/form than redirect to mydomain/app/dashboard. got it?

Comment: sorry for my english